# Rows are missing from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to have the count of assets on SalesOrderLine where SalesOrderLine.Shipped <> 'C'. The following SQL query doesn't retrieve any rows if there's no rows in SalesOrderLine or for all rows there SalesOrderLine.Shipped = 'C'.
Could you please advise where am I wrong here?

To be more specific:

- All columns have character data type (mostly nvarchar).
- If I remove

  ```
  AND SalesOrderLine.Shipped <> ''C''
  ```

  from WHERE part, it retrieves some rows. Of course it's not what I need.

Here is an example of one SO with 140 assets that for all, `SalesOrderLine.Shipped = 'C'`:

```sql
Order No    Customer Name   Customer PO Asset Count SO Status   Released    Raised Date Order Type  Address Deliveries (Connotes)
O30540  ITPG Group  IAL4445, IAL3062    140 Cancelled   NO  11/01/2015  Sold    NYIAL5554, ITPL6032 NULL
```

Here is the query:

```sql
('SELECT SalesOrderHeader.OrderNo AS [Order No], SalesOrderHeader.CustomerName AS [Customer Name], SalesOrderHeader.Reference1 AS [Customer PO], COUNT(SalesOrderLine.Barcode) AS [Asset Count], 
        LookUpData.CategoryLink AS [SO Status], (CASE WHEN isReleased = ''1'' THEN ''YES'' ELSE ''NO'' END) AS Released, SalesOrderHeader.RaisedDate AS [Raised Date], SalesOrderHeader.Ordertype AS [Order Type], 
        SalesOrderHeader.DeliverySuburb + SalesOrderHeader.DeliveryAddress1 AS [Address], (CASE WHEN LEN(pre_trimmed.DeliveryNo) < 1 THEN pre_trimmed.DeliveryNo ELSE LEFT(pre_trimmed.DeliveryNo , LEN(pre_trimmed.DeliveryNo)-1) END) AS [Deliveries (Connotes)]  
FROM SalesOrderHeader 
        INNER JOIN LookUpData ON SalesOrderHeader.Status = LookUpData.CategoryName 
        INNER JOIN SalesOrderLine ON SalesOrderHeader.OrderNo = SalesOrderLine.OrderNo 
        LEFT JOIN DeliveryHeader ON SalesOrderHeader.OrderNo = DeliveryHeader.OrderNo
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT DeliveryNo + '' ('' + Connote + ''), ''
    FROM DeliveryHeader AS intern
    WHERE DeliveryHeader.OrderNo = intern.OrderNo
    FOR XML PATH('''')
) pre_trimmed (DeliveryNo)
    WHERE 
        ' + @FieldName + ' Like ''%' + @FieldValue + '%'' 
        AND (LookUpData.Category = ''SOStatus'' AND SalesOrderLine.Shipped <> ''C'')  
    GROUP BY SalesOrderHeader.OrderNo , SalesOrderHeader.CustomerName, SalesOrderHeader.Reference1 , 
        LookUpData.CategoryLink, SalesOrderHeader.RaisedDate, SalesOrderHeader.Ordertype, 
        SalesOrderHeader.DeliverySuburb, SalesOrderHeader.DeliveryAddress1, pre_trimmed.DeliveryNo, SalesOrderHeader.isReleased 
        ORDER BY SalesOrderHeader.CustomerName, SalesOrderHeader.OrderNo')
```

Comment: Please post table structure, sample data and expected output for better clarity.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

> I do agree with Shrek and Zohar that you should include more
>   information. It will encourage someone to help you.

With that said. Here is simple change to try before you spend too much time on this. 
Replace your suspected line

```
AND SalesOrderLine.Shipped <> ''C''
```

with following line

```
AND UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SalesOrderLine.Shipped))) <> ''C''
```

Below is explanation for your handy reference.

- **Based on the symptoms you mentioned it looks like you may have unwanted white spaces or case sensitivity issue.**
- You possibly have a datatype of `Shipped` column of `SalesOrderLine` table as `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`. So I tried `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to get rid of any spaces around. *(PS - You can `TRIM` if it works with your version or even just `RTRIM` will do the job)*
- Also it is possible that you have some case sensitivity issue. Generally string comparison are not case sensitive. Though, You may possibly have some messed up settings.

@mike - See if this helps.